# UWP optional capability

Tags: uwp, appxmanifest

My UWP application might work with an external HID device. This device might be plugged or unplugged and application should react on device availability and enable\disable part of a functionality.
Is it possible to add optional capability to app manifest? Because when I have declared HID device in appmanifest annd have no device installed, I cannot even run my application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to UWP programming, I tried to declare a HID device in manifest without an external HID device, the app can still run. So I think it's not the problem with declaration. It may be the problem how you deal with this HID device.

I think you may judge if this HID device plugged or not is, before you deal with the function of HID device?

Use Windows.Devices.Enumeration API can find devices that are internally connected to the system, externally connected, or detectable over wireless or networking protocols.

Here is a link to to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt187355.aspx).

Forgive me if I'm wrong. Wish this helps you.